# Question about integration of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

LEt $f$ be a measurable function. Define $\int\limits_E f dm = \sup Y(E,f)$ where $Y(E,f) = \{ \int\limits_E \phi dm : 0 \leq \phi \leq f \}$ and $\phi$ is simple function.

and $E$ is a lebesgue measurable set. I want to show that if $B \subseteq A$, $A$ and $B$ both lebesgue measurable, and $f$ measurable function then

$$ \int\limits_B f dm \leq \int\limits_A f dm $$

My try: Pick $b \in Y(B, f) \implies b = \int\limits_B \phi $ for some simple $\phi \leq f$. Since $\phi$ is simple,  can put $\phi = \sum c_i 1_{C_i} $.

Therefore, by definition of integral of simple functions, we have

$$ \int\limits_B \phi dm = \sum c_i m( C_i \cap B) \leq_{ monotonocity} \sum c_i m(C_i \cap A) = \int\limits_A \phi dm $$

Hence, $ \int\limits_A \phi dm  $ is an upper bound for $Y(B, f)$ So we have

$$ \sup Y(B,f) = \int\limits_B f dm \leq \int\limits_A \phi dm  $$

Im stuck in this part, can we conclude from here the conclusion of the problem? Can someone help me? thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I presume you meant $B \subset A$?

Comment: .. and then $$\int_A \phi dm \leq \sup Y(A,f)$$

Comment: I feel so stupid for asking this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a \le b$, then $Y(A,a) \subset Y(A,b)$, from which it follows that $\int_A a \le \int_A b$.

Now suppose $B \subset A$. Then let $a=f\cdot 1_B, b=f$. Then $a \le b$, and so $\int_A f\cdot 1_B \le \int_A f$. Since $\int_A f\cdot 1_B = \int_B f$ we have the desired result.

Comment: I cannot vote up this answer because I have exhausted my voting previleges for today. I will when I am able to vote again in couple of hours. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all. Hopefully it helped.